# How to make a DIV (SIDEBAR) extend to the end of a scrolled page?

Tags: css, html, sidebar

I'm trying to fit a sidebar to the end of the **#SUBCONTAINER** div. this is the HTML code:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="subcontainer">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div class="logo">
            <img src="pictures/icon.png" alt="LOGO">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pagecontainer">
            <div class="page">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    footer
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and this is the CSS I'm using right now:

```
html, body {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    height:100%;
}

#container {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}

#subcontainer {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
}

#sidebar {
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#BD4538;
    color:white;
}
    .logo {
        text-align:center;
        left:50%;
        right:50%;
        border-left:-8em;
        border-right:-8em;
    }

#pagecontainer {
    width:80%;
    float:right;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:black;
}

    .page {
        padding:1em 1em 1em 1em;
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        color:black;
    }

#footer {
    clear:both;
    height:10em;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#B82928;
    color:white;
}

p {
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    text-align:justify;
    text-indent:1em;
}
```

Unfortunatelly the **SIDEBAR** DIV does not extend to the end of the parent **SUBCONTAINER** container, so if I have a longer text in **PAGECONTAINER** DIV, I will see the white background of the parent **BODY** under the **SIDEBARE** DIV.

I thought of a trick: if I change the background of the container **PAGECONTAINER** to the bgcolor of **SIDEBAR** I have what I want, but I'm working on a responsive website thus **SIDEBAR** need to change position and to go to the top of the pabe

So, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified the code little bit. Normally to make a equal height column div `display:table` `display:table-cell` property used.

```
html, body {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    height:100%;
}

#container {
    width:100%;

}

#subcontainer {
display:table;

}

#sidebar {
    width:20%;
    background-color:#BD4538;
    color:white;
 display:table-cell;
}
    .logo {
        text-align:center;
        border-left:-8em;
        border-right:-8em;
    }

#pagecontainer {
    width:80%;
  display:table-cell;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
  color:black;}
```

Working Demo link.
http://jsbin.com/mopunime/1/edit[image]

Comment: It does not work too.. the TEXT is now under the logo
see here: http://jsfiddle.net/z56S3/2/

Comment: are you talking about the footer text?

Comment: In the demo link I linked before in the comment, the footer was fine. I was talking about the Lorem ipsum's text in **#PAGECONTAINER** child of **#SUBCONTAINER**, the DIV on the right of the **SIDEBAR**.

Check out the link (http://jsfiddle.net/z56S3/2/) and you will see.

Comment: check the attached Screenshot and share your opinion.

Comment: That's what I get, as the link I linked before... http://jsfiddle.net/z56S3/2/

and here is the screenshot: http://oi61.tinypic.com/zqukn.jpg

Comment: okay so do you want the right side content at top, if the logo width is defined?
Check this Demo.. `http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/z56S3/24/`

Comment: Yes, now it works! Thank you!! Can you please tell me my mistakes, so I can learn not to make them anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "float" property from both the `#sidebar` div and the `#pagecontainer` div, and set them as `display: table-cell;`
Also, set the `#subcontainer` to `display:table` and `width:100%;`. That will make sidebar and pagecontainer to fill the subcontainer div.
Check it out:

```
html, body {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    height:100%;
}

#container {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}

#subcontainer {
    position:relative;
    display: table;
    clear:both;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    width:20%;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:#BD4538;
    color:white;
}
    .logo {
        text-align:center;
        left:50%;
        right:50%;
        border-left:-8em;
        border-right:-8em;
    }

#pagecontainer {
    width:80%;
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:black;
}

    .page {
        padding:1em 1em 1em 1em;
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        color:black;
    }

#footer {
    clear:both;
    height:10em;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#B82928;
    color:white;
}

p {
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    text-align:justify;
    text-indent:1em;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z56S3/

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work very well. The #SIDEBAR yes, now fit the parent DIV, but look what happens if I change the size of the LOGO.png the TEXT start just after the 128px height of the LOGO.png

look here: http://jsfiddle.net/z56S3/

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is that the DIV "Sidebar" fit (width or height) to the div "subcontainer" then do that:

```
#sidebar {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#BD4538;
    color:white;
}
```